# expresion FOR no reconoce Array de Objetos

Tags: java

En un sistema de login con interfaz gráfica creé una Class User cuyos atributos son (String user, String pass), luego en el Mail (principal) hardcodeé un array de usuarios (listaUser[]) con 3 users con sus respectivas passwords.

Al plantear la función para validar "user" el compilador no reconoce "i<=listaUser[].length-1".

Error: "class expected  / cannot find symbol  / symbol: class listaUser / location: class principal"

```
    public principal() {
    initComponents();
    dialogo.setSize(380,200);
    dialogo.setLocationRelativeTo(this);
    dialogo.setTitle("Inicio de sesión");
    dialogo.setVisible(true);
    User listaUser[]=new User[3];
    listaUser[0]= new User("dieduro", "codoacodo");
    listaUser[1]= new User("mengolito", "1234");
    listaUser[2]= new User("cosme", "fulanito");

} 
public boolean userok(){
    boolean userOk=false;
    for(int i=0;i<=listaUser[].length-1;i++){
        if (listaUser[i].getUser().equals(txt_user.getText())){
            userOk=true;
        }   
    }
    return userOk;
}
```

Comment: Por que le colocas -1 a `listaUser[].length`?. De esa manera el for solo recorrera dos de las 3 posiciones del array.

Comment: @David Fíjate que la comparación es `<=`, no es como se pone habitualmente pero es correcto.

Comment: error sintáctico, sustituye `listaUser[].length` por `listaUser.length`. No hace falta colocar [], el compilador sabe que es un array, los corchetes únicamente se usan para acceder a miembros o para definir el mismo array.

Comment: Tienen razón, no me habia dado cuenta lo del -1. Igualmente el error persiste aún utilizando la respuesta de @SJuan76. Habrá alguna otra cosa que estaré haciendo mal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta con que lo pongas así.

```
  public boolean userok(){
        boolean userOk=false;
        for(int i=0;i<=listaUser.length-1;i++){  ///solamente quité los corchetes.
            if (listaUser[i].getUser().equals(txt_user.getText())){
                userOk=true;
            }   
        }
        return userOk;
    }
```

Los corchetes solamente se usan cuando se quiere acceder a un elemento del arreglo, en este caso no es necesario.

Answer (score 2):

Dos errores:

- El mensaje de error sale porque `listaUser` está definido como una variable local en el método `principal`. Como tal, solo está disponible dentro de ese método; el código de otro método sencillamente no puede acceder a esta variable y por lo tanto el error. Al ejecutarse el método, el array existe mientras no se sale de él; al acabar la ejecución del método la variable "sale de ámbito", el array se queda sin ninguna referencia que lo use y en cualquier momento el *garbage collector* lo puede borrar.

  La solución más evidente es definir `listaUser` como un miembro de la clase:

  ```
  public class Principal { // El nombre de la clase siempre va en mayúsculas !!
     private User listaUser[];

     public Principal() { // El nombre de la clase siempre va en mayúsculas !!
        ...
        this.listaUser = new User[3];  // Realmente el this no es necesario, pero opino que ayuda a visualizar que la variable es un miembro de la clase.
        this.listaUser[0]= new User("dieduro", "codoacodo");
        ...
  ```

  Como miembro de la clase, ´listaUser´ será visible para los otros métodos de la misma.
- Como comenta FrEqDE, debería ser `i<=this.listaUser.length`. Aunque `listaUser` sea un array, los corchetes solo se usan cuando se quiere acceder a un elemento de éste; los otros métodos y atributos se referencian sin los corchetes. Este error no está relacionado con el mensaje de error pero te habría salido más adelante.

Comment: Hago lo que me decis pero en las lineas de `this.listaUser = new User[3];` y de `this.listaUser[0]= new User("dieduro", "codoacodo");` el compilador me arroja el error **incompatible types: User[] cannot be converted to User**. Se te ocurre por qué puede estar pasando esto?

Comment: Fallo mío, no declaraba el atributo como un array. He corregido el código.

Comment: Ahora sí! Gracias... aunque ya va siendo hora de que pueda detectar ese pequeño error sin tener que repreguntar :-P